Google Sheets spreadsheets.values.update not working when using axios
I am working on a simple internal react native application for my company. I am trying to update an excel sheet using google's apis via axios requests. I have used Google's oAuth (via Firebase) and am authenticated properly.
Here is the code (be advised that some of the variables are not used yet. I will update that when this code works):
const doWriteToGoogleSheets = async (sheetId, sheetName, range, majorDimension) => {
    await axios.put(`https://sheets.google.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/${sheetName}!${range}?valueInputOption=${VALUE_INPUT_OPTION.USER_ENTERED}&key=${AUTH_SHEETS_API_KEY}`, {
        range: `${sheetName}!${range}`,
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        values: [
            ["NAMESS"] // test value, try with only 1 cell as the range
        ],
    })

}

I have also tested using:
    await axios.put(`https://sheets.google.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/'TimeFullYear (Input Here)'!A1?valueInputOption=${VALUE_INPUT_OPTION.USER_ENTERED}&key=${AUTH_SHEETS_API_KEY}`, {
        "range": "'TimeFullYear (Input Here)'!A1",
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [
            [
                "NAMESS"
            ]
        ]
    })

and
  await axios.put(`https://sheets.google.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/'TimeFullYear (Input Here)'!A1?valueInputOption=${VALUE_INPUT_OPTION.USER_ENTERED}&key=${AUTH_SHEETS_API_KEY}`, {
        range: "TimeFullYear (Input Here)!A1",
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        values: [
            [
                "NAMESS"
            ]
        ]
    })

THE PROBLEM
My logger is saying that the code completed successfully (no error was thrown) but then I get "undefined" as a response (after the ":" is where the response should be):
SUCCESS - write to timecards: undefined

And when I check in the google sheet nothing is updated.
WHAT I KNOW

I  am  authenticated properly. I know this as my Google Sheets get request does work
I  have  enabled the required scopes (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets)

HELP
can someone help me out?
EDIT

VALUE_INPUT_OPTION.USER_ENTERED is equal to the string "USER_ENTERED"
I am following these docs: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About I am trying to update an excel sheet using google's apis via axios requests., I think that in the current stage, Sheets API cannot directly manage XLSX data. Is this related to your current issue? And, about My logger is saying that the code completed successfully (no error was thrown) but then I get "undefined" as a response (after the ":" is where the response should be):, I cannot imagine this from your showing script. Can I ask you for details of it?

By the way, although, unfortunately, I cannot understand your whole script, from your showing scripts, if you are trying to edit the Spreadsheet using an API key, in the current stage, Sheets API cannot edit the Spreadsheet using an API key. In this case, the access token is required. Please be careful about this.
